# Does Azure ACS support OpenID Connect providers?

Tags: .net, azure, openid, openid-connect, azure-acs

Is there a way to add an OpenID Connect identity provider to Azure ACS (Access Control Service).

I know we can add OpendID 2.0 as [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185935.aspx), but I do not think that it will work with new OpendID Connect protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. Active development on ACS ceased before OpenId Connect became a standard.

Comment: Thank you, can we add OpenID Connect to Azure AD or smth like that?